# Recommended Progression of Knowledge in iOS Programming?

Tags: objective-c, ios

what is the recommended progression of topics that one should pursue if they are trying to self-learn iOS programming after a solid foundation of the C programming language is established?

Answer (score 3):

How about buying an Objective-C book on amazon.

Answer (score 2):

Object Oriented Design and ObjC Memory Management -- just try porting your C programs to ObjC, learn the APIs (mostly in Foundation.framework) and see how it executes in a sampler. Then make more complex programs of great quality, then move on to UIs and more specialized frameworks you're interested in.